# Graph API PATCH updating mailEnable flag in Unified group objects

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I use Microsoft Graph API to create an Unified group and then later try to update the group to set the *mailEnabled* boolean flag to "false", the update REST call appears to be successful, but the *mailEnabled* flag isn't changed.  This is despite having other settings in the same PATCH request (such as flipping *visibility* from "Public" to "Private" or back again) which do appear to be applied.  Interestingly, I get an HTTP response code of 204 (No Content), yet the docs appear to say I should get a 200 response with a JSON version of the full group object.

The example in the documentation at http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/group_update appears to indicate the *mailEnabled* is something that you can change on a group.  If it isn't, shouldn't there be an error rather than it just succeeding but not doing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this Jon.  Couple of things:

1. Yes - this should be a 400 error.  We have a bug tracking this now.
2. Successful PATCH operations should response with a 204.  This is a doc bug. Created GitHub issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/131 to track
3. In general we could do with improving the groups reference materials.  Created GitHub issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/132

Hope this helps,